# Converting a .bat file into a Windows Scheduled Task Action

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I currently have a .bat file with this code that is called by a windows scheduled task, and it runs perfectly (**note** I am not running the entire py script, just a function from within):

```
SET PATH=c:\python27\ArcGIS10.5\;c:\Windows\system32\;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Scripts
python -c "import sys;sys.path.append(r'\\moss\scripts\Automated');import dbAudit;dbAudit.propInsDate()"
```

I am trying to remove the need for all my tasks to rely on .bat files, when the .py file resides in the same directory, and it is perfectly callable.

Just as an initial stab in the dark I have tried adding this to the Program/Script box:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

and then added this to the arguments box:

```
python -c "import sys;sys.path.append(r'\\moss\scripts\Automated');import dbAudit;dbAudit.propInsDate()"
```

This seems to fail, as I don't think my conversion is that simple, and I can see i have not included any of the 'set path' items.

Do you think that my bat file is able to be taken out of the equation and it can all be done directly in the Windows Scheduled Task?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You don't need the CMD shell at all. Use the fully-qualified path to python.exe, and the arguments could be, for example, `-c "import os, sys; os.environ['PATH'] += r'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Scripts'; sys.path.append(r'\\moss\scripts\Automated'); import dbAudit; dbAudit.propInsDate()"`.

Comment: Also, look into creating a package for your scripts that define setuptools function entry points. When installed from a wheel package, the entry points will be wrapped as executables in the "Scripts" directory, which you can run directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eryksun has provided the correct answer, but has posted it as a comment, so I cannot mark it as the correct answer, so I will paste his reply here:

> You don't need the CMD shell at all. Use the fully-qualified path to
> python.exe, and the arguments could be, for example,
>
> -c "import os,
> sys; os.environ['PATH'] +=  r'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Scripts'; sys.path.append(r'\moss\scripts\Automated'); import dbAudit; dbAudit.propInsDate()"

– eryksun Jul 20 at 1:52